# Due to cross origin anchor tag download not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I'm using anchor tag download and in through server URL I'm, trying to download the media file, It is working perfectly in Chrome(downloading the file) but in IE, MS Edge and Firefox it starting streaming the video.

This is my code:

```
<a id="lnkDownloadVid" class="btn-download" href="http://cdn.example.com/Media/ATV521Dec16.mp4" download="">
```

I try to hit the URL through jquery ajax and I got the cross-origin error.

```
//Create a simple AJAX Request to Google and alert the results
alert("Request Start");
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=http://cdn.example.com/Media/ATV521Dec16.mp4"
    },
    url: "http://cdn.example.com/Media/ATV521Dec16.mp4",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
alert("Request Ends");
```

I also tried this, but still get the cross origin error:

```
var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://cdn.example.com/Media/ATV521Dec16.mp4");
if (request) {
                // Define a callback function
                alert("Define a callback function");
                request.onload = function () { };
                // Send request
                alert("Send request");
                request.send();
            }
```

any possible solution or I'm missing something? I need to download without using server side, in other words just directly by URL.
I've button on click I need to download the file. It's working in chrome but in IE and firefox when I click on the button it starts streaming.

Comment: right-click, save-as

Comment: I need it to work on button, just in IE and Firefox on button click its start streaming.

Comment: Do you need to use ajax? Why not just let the browser download the file and the cross-origin problem goes away...

Comment: @LDj I just need to download the media file not necessarily through ajax.
I'm using 'download' attribute of anchor tag but it is not working in firefox and IE, for IE and firefox it automatically starts the media streaming.

Comment: @mplungjan, I added the preventDefault() now its not even streaming the media. Second we can not access cdn.

Comment: You only need the preventDefault for Ajax. You likely do not want Ajax anyway so forget my comment

Answer (score -1):

When answered in 2016 the issue was that the [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility) attribute is not supported by older browsers like case IE, Edge < v18, Fx < v20

Here is the compatibility chart

[image]

The issue is still present if the video is refusing to download like the one below

Unless you can change the CDN to deliver a header of application/octet-stream, I suggest this:

```js
$("#lnkDownloadVid")
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).next().show();
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="lnkDownloadVid" class="btn-download" href="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" download="">Download</a>
<span id="message" hidden>If this does not download when clicked, use the context menu (normally right click or long click on touch devices) to save</span>
```

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion but I want to force the user to click the button for download.
I'm not getting the reason why the download attribute is working on chrome but not on Firefox and IE. In firefox and IE it start the streaming.

Comment: This [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download)
said: This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

Comment: I would then guess it is actually ignored by your Chrome and downloads because your chrome has no direct support for mp4.

Comment: Might be, I'll be looking for a solution as I find it I'll post here.